# Howto change the permission of a directory to root?

Tags: command-line, permissions, mount, nautilus

Howto change the permission of a directory to root: `/mnt/sda9`?
I tried it with `gksudo`, but it says "you're not propriertary."

The following commands...

```
gksudo nautilus /mnt
sudo chown user:user /mnt/sda9
sudo chmod a+rw  /mnt/sda9
```

do not work.
With this command...

```
ls -l /mnt/sda9
retorn
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root
```

Howto change the permission to be `user:user`?

Comment: Do not use gksudo. What format is sda9? If NTFS, you cannot change as all setting are based on mount command, either manual or with fstab. Windows NTFS does not support Linux ownership & permissions. It looks like you already have permissions for everyone, which is not really recommended. Post this in question above to preserve formatting: `lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid,partuuid`

Comment: Correct is NTFS, the solution is formatting in FAT. Thank you very much

Comment: FAT32 is also a Microsoft design that does not support Linux ownership & permissions. Again mount parameters set defaults. And FAT32 does not support files over 4GB, so not recommended for larger partitions. OK of smaller partitions like ESP where data is not written a lot. FAT32 also does not have journel that newer partitions like NTFS & ext4 support. A file check on large partition could take a very long time.